# Yocto not packaging symlink to shared object

Tags: yocto, bitbake, libftdi

I'm trying to install libft4222 on my target image. libft4222 is a dependency for another recipe I'm using to add an application to the target image.

I've taken the example from the [yocto manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/prebuilt-libraries.html#versioned-libraries) for versioned libraries and adjusted it accordingly to download the relevant sources:

```
SUMMARY = "FTDI FT4222H Library"
SECTION = "libs"
LICENSE_FLAGS = "ftdi"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

# Sources available in a .tgz file in .zip archive
# at https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/libft4222-linux-1.4.4.44.zip
# Found on https://ftdichip.com/software-examples/ft4222h-software-examples/

SRC_URI = "https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/libft4222-linux-${PV}.tgz"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "b92ca18e4d8d6aafed31b5f74d0822fae071de7ac6b88e5fe9427e14e1dc9b11"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

ARCH_DIR:x86-64 = "build-x86_64"
ARCH_DIR:i586 = "build-i386"
ARCH_DIR:i686 = "build-i386"
ARCH_DIR:raspberrypi4 = "build-arm-v7-hf"

do_install () {
        install -m 0755 -d ${D}${libdir}
        oe_soinstall ${S}/${ARCH_DIR}/libft4222.so.${PV} ${D}${libdir}
        install -d ${D}${includedir}
        install -m 0755 ${S}/*.h ${D}${includedir}
}

SOLIBS = "${libdir}/libft4222.so.${PV}"
FILES:${PN} += "${libdir}/*.so ${libdir}/*.so.${PV}"
```

In my application recipe I added libft4222 as `DEPENDS` as well as `RDEPENDS` dependency. My application builds properly and is added to the image rootfs, but libft4222 only installs the versioned .so file `libft4222.so.${PV}` and omits the symlink `libft4222.so`.

I need to have the symlink deployed as well, I tried by manually installing the library and symlink instead of `oe_soinstall` as well:

```
install -m 0755 ${S}/${ARCH_DIR}/libft4222.so.${PV} ${D}${libdir}
ln -r -s ${D}${libdir}/libft4222.so.${PV} ${D}${libdir}/libft4222.so
```

But this leads to the same behaviour.

In my local.conf file I added both recipes to the build:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " libft4222 application-recipe"
```

In the working directory I see both files being generated under `libft4222/${PV}/image/usr/lib/` but only the versioned file is added to rootfs. What am I missing here?

I'm using yocto Kirkstone and libft4222 verion 1.4.4.44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution through [this thread](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2017-April/035522.html):

yocto treats unversioned .so files so that they are only packaged to the libft4222-dev package. In order to package them for the non-dev package as well skip the `dev-so` step:

```bash
SUMMARY = "FTDI FT4222H Library"
SECTION = "libs"
LICENSE_FLAGS = "ftdi"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

# Sources available in a .tgz file in .zip archive
# at https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/libft4222-linux-1.4.4.44.zip
# Found on https://ftdichip.com/software-examples/ft4222h-software-examples/

SRC_URI = "https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/libft4222-linux-${PV}.tgz"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "b92ca18e4d8d6aafed31b5f74d0822fae071de7ac6b88e5fe9427e14e1dc9b11"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

ARCH_DIR:x86-64 = "build-x86_64"
ARCH_DIR:i586 = "build-i386"
ARCH_DIR:i686 = "build-i386"
ARCH_DIR:raspberrypi4 = "build-arm-v7-hf"

do_install () {
        install -m 0755 -d ${D}${libdir}
        oe_soinstall ${S}/${ARCH_DIR}/libft4222.so.${PV} ${D}${libdir}
        install -d ${D}${includedir}
        install -m 0755 ${S}/*.h ${D}${includedir}
}

# skip dev-so in order for the unversioned so file to be packaged as well
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""
INSANE_SKIP:${PN} += "dev-so"
FILES:${PN} += "${libdir}/libft4222.so ${libdir}/libft4222.so.${PV}"
```